# Existe alguma forma de deixar a connection string em C#?

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, .net, segurança

Estou utilizando .NET 7 e atualmente eu deixo minha connection string no appsettings.json, porém eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de guardar a connection string de uma forma mais segura para que não fique explicita no appsettings.json

Comment: Seu `appsettings.json` está exposto para ser acessado via http? Se sim, então a falha de segurança não é com o appsettings.json, se não vem a segunda pergunta, só você tem acesso ao servidor? Se não, o problema não será com o appsettings.json, será com quem tem acesso, pois uma pessoa com acesso assim poderá fazer qualquer coisa, independente de onde colocar os dados de acesso ao banco.

Comment: Uma das opções é deixar como variável de ambiente ou usar algum sistema de segredos como Azure Key Vault ou Consul Vault. Mas você precisa entender bem qual a sua real necessidade. Como disse o @SerialCodingExperiments, se seu appSettings está visível externamente o problema está em outro lugar (na exposição desse arquivo, no caso), caso outras pessoas tenham acesso ao server, talvez seja uma boa opção controlar os acessos de forma mais granular e assim por diante...